# Is it safe to drop/delete mysql 'user'@'host' leftover from previous web host?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have the following MySQL users and hosts.
Away from root, the user 'usern' is my cPanel account username, the users (leechprotect, modsec, roundcube, cphulkd, eximstats) are cPanel related (those have no problem as they are connected only to 'localhost').
The other 7 accounts are connected to **more than one mysql HOST**. Each of the 7 mysql users (usern_an, usern_anup, usern_mup, usern_up, usern_upp, usern_vb, usern_vb3, usern_vbtu,  ) is connected to a database.

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;                                       
+----------------+------------------------------+  
| User           | Host                         |  
+----------------+------------------------------+  
| usern         | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| usern_an      | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| usern_anup    | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| usern_mup     | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |   
| usern_up      | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| usern_upp     | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| usern_vb      | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| usern_vb3     | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| usern_vbtu    | ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1                 |  
| root          | 127.0.0.1                    |  
| usern         | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern_an      | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern_anup    | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |   
| usern_mup     | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern_up      | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern_upp     | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern_vb      | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern_vb3     | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern_vbtu    | ip2.ip2.ip2.ip2                |  
| usern         | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern_an      | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern_anup    | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern_mup     | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern_up      | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern_upp     | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |   
| usern_vb      | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern_vb3     | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern_vbtu    | ip3.ip3.ip3.ip3                |  
| usern         | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_an      | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_anup    | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_mup     | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_up      | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_upp     | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_vb      | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_vb3     | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern_vbtu    | ip4.ip4.ip4.ip4               |  
| usern         | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_an      | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_anup    | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_mup     | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_up      | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_upp     | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_vb      | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_vb3     | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern_vbtu    | ip5.ip5.ip5.ip5                |  
| usern         | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_an      | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_anup    | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_mup     | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_up      | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_upp     | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_vb      | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_vb3     | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| usern_vbtu    | ip6.ip6.ip6.ip6                 |  
| root          | ::1                          |  
| usern         | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_an      | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_anup    | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_mup     | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_up      | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_upp     | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_vb      | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_vb3     | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern_vbtu    | c1server.domserverC.com |  
| usern         | gserver.domserverA.com  |  
| usern_an      | gserver.domserverA.com |  
| usern_anup    | gserver.domserverA.com |   
| usern_mup     | gserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern_up      | gserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern_upp     | gserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern_vb      | gserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern_vb3     | gserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern_vbtu    | gserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern         | iserver.domserverB.com          |  
| usern_an      | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| usern_anup    | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| usern_mup     | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| usern_up      | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| usern_upp     | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| usern_vb      | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| usern_vb3     | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| usern_vbtu    | iserver.domserverB.com             |  
| cphulkd        | localhost                    |  
| eximstats      | localhost                    |  
| usern         | localhost                    |  
| usern_an      | localhost                    |  
| usern_anup    | localhost                    |  
| usern_mup     | localhost                    |  
| usern_up      | localhost                    |   
| usern_upp     | localhost                    |  
| usern_vb      | localhost                    |  
| usern_vb3     | localhost                    |  
| usern_vbtu    | localhost                    |  
| leechprotect   | localhost                    |  
| modsec         | localhost                    |  
| root           | localhost                    |  
| roundcube      | localhost                    |  
| usern         | mserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern_vb      | mserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern_vbtu    | mserver.domserverA.com          |  
| root           | mserver.domserverA.com          |  
| usern         | server.domserverA.net        |  
| usern_vb      | server.domserverA.net        |  
| usern_vbtu    | server.domserverA.net        |  
| usern         | server1.domserverD.com       |  
| usern_an   | server1.domserverD.com       |  
| usern_anup | server1.domserverD.com       |  
| usern_mup     | server1.domserverD.com       |  
| usern_up      | server1.domserverD.com       |  
| usern_upp     | server1.domserverD.com       |  
| usern_vb      | server1.domserverD.com       |  
| usern_vb3     | server1.domserverD.com       |  
+----------------+------------------------------+  
113 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Indeed only ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1 is my current ip with current web host.
Away from 'localhost' and 'ip1.', the other ips and server names are from previous web hosts.

Is it safe to drop/delete those 'user'@'host's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be safe and there would be no issue at backend to access db.

For your convenience, You can re-create root user as [here](http://www.helpfromfriend.com/featured/how-to-recreate-root-account-in-mysql/) if problem comes.

Example:

```
mysql -u root
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option;
```

Comment: This is only a general idea. deleting those 'user'@'host's would break my site if it has anything to do with retrieving data from database.  If someone knows why or how those connections between users and 'old' hosts are made, then it would be safe to take action.

Comment: I need ALL my 8 mysql users, not just root! I'll edit main question to add this.

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what accounts are not used by running

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

This should give you an idea about current sessions along with with users.

Make sure that user invoking this command has [PROCESS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege or simply use root account (if you have access to it)

Reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html).

Comment: What's the use of current sessions and users of these sessions? Any how I have 3 users in output: eximstats,  (15 Ids), root (2 Ids), leechprotect (1 Id). All on 'localhost'.